# Web.py sql query, why we can only traverse the result at the first time?

Tags: python, mysql, database, web.py

Here is my code:

```
import web
user_db = web.database(dbn='mysql', ....)

info_list = user_db.query("select * from tablename where t_id= ")
for info in info_list:
# work ok at first time, print the correct id
    print info.id

for info in info_list: 
# Code can't reach here 
    print info.id
```

The second time for each seems not work. Why?

Comment: @alecxe it works, thank you. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/db.py#L661-L671), the underlying `query()` call returns an *iterator*, which is getting exhausted after the first loop.

If you need to iterate over it multiple times, convert it to a list:

```
info_list = list(user_db.query("select * from tablename where t_id= "))
```

Or, you can use [`itertools.tee()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to create new iterators:

```
info_list1, info_list2 = itertools.tee(info_list)
```